# How to attach valve to fridge compressor copper pipe without torch?

Tags: air-conditioning, valve, compressor, welding

I'm trying to make a vacuum pump to pump my car's AC system.

I have a fridge outside with r600a gas. I am wanting to take out the compressor and use it as a vacuum pump.

I don't even know if the compressor works but it's worth a shot.

All I need to do is attach 2 valves onto the 2 copper pipes on the compressor, the electrical is setup already on the compressor.

I don't have an acetylene torch, is there another DIY way to attach the valve to make it leak proof. The valve will come with a short length of copper pipe attached to it.

The valve will fit onto my manifold  gauge set hose etc.

Comment: An acetylene torch would burn though copper in a second.  You want a propane torch(10/15 dollars) and some solder.  Check google for soldering copper pipes.  There are also compression/push to fit fittings available for most weird ideas for joining copper pipes together.  Most fridge compressors are used as DIY air compressors/pumps.  Do think it would be better to go to local scrap yard and find right vacuum pump for your car.

Comment: I mean I want to pull a vacuum on the AC system in my car, you need to do that before you can recharge the AC gas. Instead of buying a pump you can use the compressor in fridge as a vacuum pump. I just need to work out how to attach a 1/4 hose connection to the copper pipe I will cut on the fridge compressor.

Comment: In that case if pipes are same size, could probably just use rubber/plastic type hose(fuel hose) and a couple of hose champs.  Have pipes butt against each other.  Can also search google for different fittings for hose to pipe sizes.  Fridge pipes usually on small side so 1/4 hose might just fit over(with lubrication) with a champ to tighten.

Comment: Yeh I see that now, plastic hose and clamps are the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @crisp659 an oxy acetylene torch is used to silver solder hvac copper components, propane is not hot enough there are some lower temp solders that will work with mapp gas but these solders are not strong enough for R410 and other high pressure refrigerants, the solder used in potable water is a recipe for an explosive decompression.

Comment: At all ppl here:  Is a fridge compressor ANYWHERE NEAR a real vacuum pump needed to draw down the pressure to near zero before recharging? This is craziness. Pumping down a refrigerant based system requires specialized  equipment, not a hack job from a potentially useless fridge compressor that the OP doesn't even know if it works or not. I'm voting to close bc this is just to crazy.  ----

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's just not related to normal home improvement questions. The OP is proposing a total hack job with potentially dangerous results. This doesn't belong on SE.

Comment: @AndyS -- if you need help with a car issue, mechanics.SE is the place to ask that, BTW.

Comment: This is about HVAC , compressors, refrigerant etc not sure that auto problems.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel This is not a car issue (maintenance or repair), it is "how do I "hack" or build X... So not relevant on mechanics either...

Answer (score 1):

Yes a refrigerator compressor can pull a vacuum but it may not last long because as you reach a vacuum there is no air to transfer the heat away from the windings.

The heat buildup and motor failure this is something taught in hvac training when you pump Down a system using its own compressor.

you don’t run it at a vacuum or you will smoke the compressor motor.

Using rubber  or plastic parts will collapse and rubber will offgas and prevent you from ever achieving a vacuum.

Although it requires a license to charge a hvac system ( epa 609 for a motor vehicle) they sell R134a  in auto parts stores so pulling a vacuum is what you should do the requirements state 500um but you won’t get that with your setup.

Since you don’t have an proper torch invest in a BPV31
Bullet piercing valve, fits 1/4”, 5/16 & 3/8 copper lines (remember copper tubing is measured on OD not ID like pipe is.
The copper pipe is not what you use for a water line it is thicker (you could use acr copper for water lines but it is more expensive because of the thicker wall).

Clean the paint off the copper, put the valve in on the line and tighten the 3 screws.
Then pierce (they come with instructions) the valves cost ~2.50 ea .

The only question is what are you going to do with the refrigerant in the system?
Did you know there are up to $25,000.00 fines in the US if reported.

The bullet piercing valve is a part I have on hand to pump down things like Refrigerators into my recovery system. Then I usually install a standard valve but the BPV31 is designed to be left in place. I pull a vacuum and then add the refrigerant by weight, don’t over charge that can damage the compressor.

When pulling the car down watch the gauges if the compressor fails shut your gauges off or you will loose what you did get.

Edit I just thought of this, hope it helps.

Note the BPH is a 1/4” standard flair valve if your gauges use acme threads I don’t know if there is a bullet valve with acme type threads used on newer cars but there are adapters to convert 1/4” flair to acme that’s what I use because I don’t do much auto but have the 609 License ( a friend got turned in he had the 608 license and did not get the fine because got the 609 license before the court date).

Comment: Well if your talking about the fridge gas it's r600a which isn't deemed dangerous to the atmosphere in the UK, as for the gas in the car AC, I doubt there is any left. Also are you saying that even gas rated plastic tubing rated up to 14bar will not pull a sufficient vacuum on the car AC, I find that hard to believe, you will never get a 100% vacuum anyway.

Comment: I have not used R600a. I remember iso-butane being discussed because of its flammability.  When you are thinking of vacuum you would be going down to zero bar that’s what the compressor would be getting close to. Things that are normally fine start offgasing when put in a vacuum. I provided a very inexpensive method that is used by professionals to access the vacuum that the compressor can create using a hvac gauge set. When we purchase copper tubing it is dehydrated and purged with inert gas so we don’t have to wait all day for moisture to be pulled out of the system. Trying to provide help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to pull a vacuum 0n an A/C system is not just to remove the air. The real reason to pull a vacuum on the system is to yes, remove the air, but is also to remove any moisture that will get into the system when the lines are cut and the removed compressor is exposed to the atmosphere. What you are trying to do has some merit but in no way is the same a evacuating a system to remove the moisture that is entrained in the oil. It is this moisture that will kill a refrigerant system not the air. Before you waste your time trying to use a "short cut" to evacuate an A/C system even the one in your car, take it to a professional that re-charges these systems and have it done right. My 2 cents.

Comment: True if a 500 um vacuum is not achieved any moisture in the system will be left. Moisture and compressor at a bad mix. oil any type synthetic or natural turns acidic. On an electric compressor can wipe out the motor in just a few days as the insulation “varnish” on the windings is dissolved and they short, car systems may last longer with the internals of the compressor including the coils being etched away and ruining the system so it can not be repaired. A fully functioning hvac compressor may make 1000 um that’s not low enough. The EPA suggest 500 um most pros go down to 100 or less.